# Preserve leading zero in csv file using javascript

Tags: javascript, csv, formatting, export-to-csv

I am downloading a csv using the following code.

```
<a download="somedata.csv"  id='x'>Download CSV</a>
<script>
       var csv = '01'; //prints 1 in the cell, truncating leading zero
       var csv = "'"+01+"'"; //prints '01' in the cell, with single quote
       var csv = '"\""01"\""'; //prints "01" in the cell, with double quotes
       var a = document.getElementById('x');
       a.href='data:text/csv;base64,' + btoa(csv);
</script>
```

I need to print the numbers with leading zeroes in the csv file. The solution I have found so far is to make the number a text by wrapping it either with single or double quotes. But this does not solve the problem as it prints the quotes also in the cell.

Isn't there a way to preserve the leading zeroes and print the numbers without quotes in the cell? Any suggestions?

EDIT: I forgot to mention in the original post that I MUST need to open the csv in Excel.

```
var csv = "'01";   //prints '01 in the cell
var csv = '="01"'; //prints  01 in the cell, but the value is ="01"
```

Isn't there a way to get the cell value and display both as 01 (instead of different display and value)?

Comment: Please indicate the manner in which you have determined that the leading zero is stripped. This crucial factor is, if I'm right, the cause of the problem, yet you did not include it in your problem description!

Answer (score 4):

I know it is an old question, but I recently came across this issue and fixed it by adding Zero-Width-Space character at the end like this :

```
var csv = '01' + String.fromCharCode(8203);
```

I hope it will help others who come across this issue.

Comment: Unfortunately this code adds this character when displayed in Excel 365: _â€‹_

Answer (score 2):

```
<a download="somedata.csv"  id='x'>Download CSV</a>
<script>
       var csv = '01';
       var a = document.getElementById('x');
       a.href='data:text/csv;base64,' + btoa(csv);
</script>
```

This works just fine as it is.

I imagine that you're viewing the CSV in Excel, which re-formats the number according to its whims and to cell defaults. But if you look at the CSV in Notepad, you'll see that the leading `0` is still there in the actual file.

Answer (score 2):

Your code actually works:

```
<a download="somedata.csv"  id='x'>Download CSV</a>
<script>
       var csv = '01';
       var a = document.getElementById('x');
       a.href='data:text/csv;base64,' + btoa(csv);
</script>
```

If you open this file in a text-editor the leading zero is present.

If you are specifically targeting Microsoft Excel, you can add a leading single-quote to preserve the leading zero - although you'll still need to enter each cell and hit enter to make it take effect!:

```
<a download="somedata.csv"  id='x'>Download CSV</a>
<script>
       var csv = "'01";
       var a = document.getElementById('x');
       a.href='data:text/csv;base64,' + btoa(csv);
</script>
```

More convoluted - but works (again only for Excel)

```
<a download="somedata.csv"  id='x'>Download CSV</a>
<script>
       var csv = '="01"';
       var a = document.getElementById('x');
       a.href='data:text/csv;base64,' + btoa(csv);
</script>
```

Comment: To be specific, this forces Excel to see the 'cell' contents as text rather than formatting it as a number. Though as you say this makes the file non-portable.

Comment: Yes - the only fix I can think of that would work in Excel and everywhere else would be to have a line of headings, then a line of dummy data that were all strings, then the real data from line 3. Excel looks ahead a few lines when determining the data-type, so data with a string would force the formatter not to choose a numeric type.

Comment: I don't see a need for any "fix" so far. The value Excel shows is correct. The leading zero has no semantic significance. Unfortunately the OP hasn't explained why he or she cares.

Comment: I worked at a pension company who had accounts migrated from companies it acquired. In that case, the difference between `0094569` and `094569` was dead important.

Comment: Data that _must_ be interpreted should be quoted in CSV files; if Excel doesn't properly parse that than it's silly.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue with CSV file, what I have found that adding a leading TAB character with number makes it work.

```
let csv = '\t'+'01';
```

This will preserve this leading zero and TAB is ignored by Excel