# Prevent Javascript Excel Conversion from removing Leading 0

Tags: javascript

After Converting an Object to Excel Format, The Final Output removes the leading 0 from the Column "Application ID".

[image]

Image Showing an Application ID where those values start with **leading 0** (i.e. 0799, 0791)

Here is the sample code (trimmed to minimal)

```
exportCSV() {
  let csvContent = "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,";
  let universalBOM = "\uFEFF";
    let dataArray = this.MyFacilitiesData.map(item => {
      const { applicationId } = item
      const extract = { "Application ID": applicationId}
      return extract;
    });
    const array = [Object.keys(dataArray[0])].concat(dataArray);
    let converted = universalBOM +
                    array.map(content => Object.values(content).toString()).join("\n");
    csvContent += converted + "\r\n";
    var encodedUri = encodeURI(csvContent);
 }
```

where I use encodeUri to make it download as excel.  How can i prevent the removal of leading 0?

Comment: Put quotes around the value?

Comment: What is the data type of `applicationId`? Did you try to convert  the value to string: `applicationId.toString()`?

Comment: @Shuvo applicationID is getting from API and yes it is coming as a string already.

Comment: @HereticMonkey yes I tried, no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the error by adding

```
applicationId + String.fromCharCode(8203)
```

After fixing:

[image]

Reference:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/55516747/9536402

Answer (score 0):

Excel loves to remove leading zeros from numbers. You can prevent this by having an apostrophe at the start of the number. Example:

```
'0799
```

I think you could do this:

```
const extract = { "Application ID": `'${applicationId}`}
```

Comment: It works but gives me an entry like this '"001" for 001. How do I remove the double quotes. Tried doing `'${Number(applicationId)}` but then it gives 'NaN